# how come I could create a json-type file in django project?

Tags: python, django

I just start to learn django and Vue.js and now face this problem.
I have built a small python + django + Vue.js project according to the sample.
It works well now. the main codes are as follows:

> testdjango.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="mineapp">
    {{msg}}
        <form @submit.prevent ="submitNote">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="formData.title"/>
            <label>Content</label>
            <textarea v-model="formData.content"></textarea>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
  import api from './api/index.js'
....
     methods: {
        submitNote(){
          api.fetchNotes('post',null, this.formData).then(res=>{
            this.msg = 'Saved'
          }).catch((e)=>{
          this.msg = e.response
          })
      },
```

> index.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default{
    fetchNotes(method, params, data){
    if(method ==='post'){
      return ajax('api/notes/', method,{data})
    } else{
      return ajax('api/notes/', 'get', {})
    }
...
function ajax(url,method,options){
    if(options !== undefined){
        var{params=[], data={}} = options
    } else{
        params = data = {}
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    axios({
    url,
    method,
    params,
    data
    }).then(res => {
    resolve(res)
    }, res=>{
    reject(res)
    })
})
```

> models.py

```
class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, auto_now_add=True)
    def _str_(self):
        return self.title
```

> views.py

```
class NoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    #check permissions
    permission_classes={
        IsAuthenticated,
    }
    queryset = Note.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
    lookup_field ="id"
```

I successfully stored the front-end data into backend-side(django) and checked admin panel.

> Next problem is that:

when I send a ajax request "/api/notes" can I create a json-type file in local drive of django project?
I want to create a json-type file created in django side and save my local project directory.
But I don't know how to do that? With one request can I do two functions(store data into django model and create a json-type file in django project)?

Answer (score 0):

For generating `JSON` files you can use the `json` module, just create a `dictionary` with the data, open a `file` for `writing` and just `dump` the data in it, this will work:

```py
import json


dictionary = {
    'key': 'value'
}


file_path = 'a/file/path.json'
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    json.dump(dictionary, file)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! where do I have to add this code? views.py?